# ¿Como embeber html dentro de un correo y que este lo ejecute?

Tags: java, html, html5, jsp

Buen día

Hoy nuevamente recurro a este maravilloso sitio para despajar ciertas dudas sobre como hacer para enviar código html en el contenido de un correo y que este se ejecute.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda, en especial si la respuesta que me dan es haciendo uso de Java.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

Answer (score 1):

En la sección de Stackoverflow en inglés hay una respuesta para tu pregunta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-an-html-email